# Get a grand total from several counts

Tags: t-sql

I just need the grand total which is adding each count below and this is not working for me, I get "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.":

```
DECLARE @total int

SET @total = Count(some select statement)

@total = @total + Count(some select statement)
@total = @total + Count(some select statement)
@total = @total + Count(some select statement)
.. and so on

-- now return the grand total
select @total
```

or if you think there is even an easier or more efficient way to do this, I'm all ears too.

Comment: Looks like you have the correct idea, you are missing a SET on the three lines in the middle.

Comment: @DavidSteele you can't use 'set' in combination with 'count' as shown in my answer

Comment: You can do this though.... SET @total += (SELECT COUNT(*) from sometable)

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @total int = 0

select @total += count(*) from (select 1 col1) a
select @total += count(*) from (select 1 col1) a
select @total += count(*) from (select 1 col1) a

select @total
```